# JavaScript If...Else Statement Error

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am very new to JavaScript and have a rather simple code error I can't resolve...

The code I have included below is supposed to return 'OK' if the text 'spring' is typed in the text box after a button click and 'ERROR' if anything else's input.  as the code is written below it returns 'OK' just after the button click but if i put the  == or === after my 'if' statement I get 'ERROR' no matter what.

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var x="";
    if (textfield = "spring"){
        x="OK";
    }else{
        x="ERROR";
    }
    document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You could also do something like `var x = (textfield === "spring") ? "OK" : "ERROR";` and save a lot of noise.

Comment: We first need to know what textfield is. We likely need document.getElementsByName("textfield")[0].value or document.getElementById("textfield").value

Comment: If there's an error with what `textfield` is then we need to see more context. Without knowing more, I'd guess you set the value on page load rather than retrieving the value at the time `myFunction` is being executed.

Comment: Here is what I believe to be all the relevant code to help get a more complete picture...

Comment: in header: <script>
function myFunction()
{
var x="";
if (textfield.value === "hacc")
  {
  x="OK";
  }
else
  {
  x="ERROR";
  }
document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

Comment: in body: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="textfield">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="validate"></p>

</form>

Answer (score 2):

You're not comparing but assigning.

Supposing `textfield` is a string, change

```
if (textfield = "spring")
```

to

```
if (textfield === "spring")
```

If `textfield` is your input, use

```
if (textfield.value === "spring")
```

Comment: OP has actually done that i think. `on click but if i put the == or === after my 'if' statement I get 'ERROR`

Comment: ok, assigning it a value and using the === it now checks out in Dreamweaver but in a browser it doesn't do either if/else command

Answer (score 0):

== stands for "is equal to" != stands for "is not equal to".

Comment: Better to explicitly contrast with what the OP is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have to use == as destroy says to do a comparison. Where is textfield being assigned a value?

Maybe try `function myFunction(textfield)` and calling your function with a value:

`myFunction('spring');`

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `if (textfield = "spring")`
in the above code you are using '=', there is a lot of difference between '=', '==' and '==='.
= -> assignment Operator
== -> Data Comparision
=== -> Datatype comparision then data comparision (first the type of the operands will be compared, if thats successfull then the data inside the operands will be compared)

as you are using '=', it is assigning "spring" to your variable "textfield"

just replace your if condition with  `if (textfield === "spring")`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
var textfield = document.text.textfield.value;`
var x="";
if (textfield == "spring"){
    x="OK";
}else{
    x="ERROR";
}
document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
<form name="text">
<input type="text" name="textfield" />
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p><span id="validate"></span></p>
```

hope that helps abit